# How to expose a Restful Endpoint in Play Framework for uploading a File and Posting a JSON at the same time?

Tags: json, scala, rest, file-upload, playframework

I am using Play Framework 2.5.x with Scala

I need to expose a POST Endpoint where it is possible to post a Json and upload a file as part of the same Request.

As a requirement I need to use **multipart/form-data**

I cannot have any type of form as suggested in this link:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaFileUpload#Direct-file-upload

**How to do that?**

Comment: What does your request look like? As far as I know, the body of a request can only contain one bit of content.

Comment: Hi @irundaia, it should contain:  POST  /endpoint  {  property: "property", property2: "value" }

+ File in multipartform

Answer (score 0):

I guess this test case lines can explain it better

```
val part = FilePart[TemporaryFile](key = "picture", filename = "image.JPG", contentType = Some("image/jpeg"), ref = mockFile)
val data = Map("property1" -> "property1")
val formData: MultipartFormData[TemporaryFile] = MultipartFormData(dataParts = data, files = Seq(part), badParts = Seq(), missingFileParts = Seq())
val request = FakeRequest(POST, "/uploadFileWithJson").withMultipartFormDataBody(formData)
```

So if you want to pass data with file upload you can send it as Map like "data" in the above example and in actual controller side you can do like this:-

```
request.body.asMultipartFormData.get.dataParts
```

Above will contain the data Map

```
request.body.asMultipartFormData.get.file("picture")
```

This will contain the file.

Comment: Your solution does not really work, if you pass the JSON as a String from a HTP client, it is not possible to get it back. I am using Play 2.5

case class MultipartFormData[A](dataParts: Map[String, Seq[String]], files: Seq[FilePart[A]], badParts: Seq[BadPart])

Comment: I am not sure what is your actual problem now but 
`request.body.asMultipartFormData.get.dataParts`
will contain the Map which you have sent and if you want Json of that you can always use `Json.toJson(mapOfData)`
Let me know if I got your point wrong.