# How to Upload a File and post a Json in one Single "Atomic Rest Operation"

Tags: scala, rest, file-upload, playframework, multipartform-data

At the question:

[How to expose a Restful Endpoint in Play Framework for uploading a File and Posting a JSON at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38030373/how-to-expose-a-restful-endpoint-in-play-framework-for-uploading-a-file-and-post)

I wanted to know how in one Single HTTP request POST/ I could upload a file and send a Json. My intention was to maintain my API restful.

After some research, I came across the following answer, that basically suggests to post the metadata firstly and then post the file as **multi-part**, like in two separate operation, associating the two:

[How do I upload a file with metadata using a REST web service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938569/how-do-i-upload-a-file-with-metadata-using-a-rest-web-service)

My question is, how can I do this as an Atomic Operation in My Restful API?

Since I am having 2 steps to finish up the operation, how do I ensure I don;t process the metadata without the file, in case the second post(upload) with the file is not performed by the client?

**What are my architectural choices?**

I am using Play Framework 2.5 with Scala (no views, completely restful)

Comment: Is this a duplication of [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38030373/how-to-expose-a-restful-endpoint-in-play-framework-for-uploading-a-file-and-post)? If so, I suggest you to close/remove one of them to avoid splitting the discussion.

Comment: @marcospereira - No it's not, in the other question I am asking how to do in one single HTTP request, no round trips...
Here I am asking how to manage to HTTP POST requests.

Comment: Have you found any response, that you like to share ?